# Constructor for prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In file meterA.js I have this

```
    window.MeterA = function(options)
    {
        return this.init(options);
    }

   MeterA.prototype = {
        init: function(options) {
            this.container = options.container;
            this.width = options.width;
            this.height = options.height;
            this.sliderSize = options.sliderSize;
            var Canvas = {
                meter: TBE.CreateRectCanvasElement (displayWidth, displayHeight),
                slider: TBE.CreateSquareCanvasElement (sliderSize)
            };
            Container.appendChild (Canvas.meter);
            Container.appendChild (Canvas.slider);
        }
    }
```

Then in file pane.html, I tried to initialise meter with:

```
var MeterA = new MeterA({
    container:  Div.meterA, 
    width:      GetNumberIgnoreUnit(Div.speedMeter.style.width, 2), 
    height:     GetNumberIgnoreUnit(Div.speedMeter.style.height, 2), 
    sliderSize: 10
});
```

But I get "MeterA is not a constructor" as error, why is it?

Comment: Are you sure you are including the JavaScript file in that page.. ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling the variable `MeterA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MeterA = new MeterA({ ...
```

I believe using MeterA as the variable name and the class name is the problem here. Variable declarations in Javascript are "hoisted" to the top of the function so MeterA becomes undefined

Some good explanation here : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

Comment: Thanks, just a careless mistake on my part... but i got to learn abt javascript hoisting! Sth new to me! But i don't think hoisting can be applied in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Smth along these lines should work :

```
var MeterA = (function () {

    // constructor
    var MeterA = function (options) {
        this.init(options);
    };

    // prototype
    MeterA.prototype = {
        init: function (options) {
            console.log(options);
        }
    };

    return MeterA;

})();

obj = new MeterA({
    opt1: 'sasa',
    opt2: false
});
```

I recomend [Javascript Patterns 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) for a more in-depth overview of the constructor pattern .

Another good read about javascript [Essential JavaScript Design Patterns For Beginners, Volume 1.](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript)